# Does Rails have an "active?" method on ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at "fields_for" helper doc at [Rails API website](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many). The following piece of code confuses me.

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
...
  <%= person_form.fields_for :projects do |project_fields| %>
    <% if project_fields.object.active? %>
      Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

Does anyone have an idea about what "acitve?" is? It looks like a method on the ActiveRecord object, but I can't find any doc/reference about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No (ActiveModel) doesn't, but you are actually asking about the object generated by fields_for.

Comment: Got it. "active?" should be a method defined on model Project here. Thanks @errata